# Node Connection Error While contacting MySql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, express

I wrote a connector to get the data from the mysql and when iam running the Mysql connector inside a route it is showing error and the browser  is running into  a infinite loop.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Connect to Mongoose

//mongoose.connect('mongodg://localhost/malwares');
//var db = mongoose.connection()


//Connect to Mysql
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '192.168.150.94',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'negalkgkgkal',
  database : 'dbnamehere'
});

connection.connect();

//connection.query('SELECT * from detection', function(err, rows, fields) {
  //if (!err)
    //console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  //else
  // console.log('Error while performing Query.');
//});

//connection.end();
//Mysql connection ends

app.get('/' , function(req ,res){
        res.send('Goto /api/malware for detection results');
});
app.get('/malwares' , function(req , res){
        console.log('Hello');
        connection.query('SELECT * from rest', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err)
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  else
   console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});
});

connection.end()
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Error Log

```
Listening on port 3000
Hello
Error while performing Query.
```

And also the browser is not responding after this.

I even tried using node-inspector it gave me error like this `protocol-enqueue-after-fatal-error-in-node-mysql`

Any suggestions on how to solve this error?

P.S :: Database is there and also the table exists,for this purpose of error debugging i have queried another table which i commented in the code and it ran succesfully.

Error:

```
{ Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/var/www/Rest/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:202:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/Rest/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:13)
    at Connection.query (/var/www/Rest/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
    at /var/www/Rest/app.js:39:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/Rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/www/Rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/www/Rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/Rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /var/www/Rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/Rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false }
```

Comment: can you post what you see when you console.log(err) in else block?

Comment: ah, don't call connection.end(), you are closing connection before you query .

Comment: Then when to call connection.end() method ??

Comment: If you are writing a server(you are), you don't call connection.end() until you want to stop responding to the requests. With servers, you might want to call it before server process ends.

Comment: this means that you have some error innyour query, are you sure that fron the table name?

Comment: @hassan no . After i deleted connection.end() code working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you don't need connection.connect() part if connection is defined in same file (like you have), you try commenting out that line and then run it.
I know, I encountered some problems because of that